# How to export mysqldump XML schema like with phpmyadmin?

Tags: xml, phpmyadmin, schema, mysql

When I use the phpmyadmin XML export option, I obtain one XML file like this:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58710351/db1.xml

However, when I use mysqldump, programming a cron with mysqldump --xml -u name -ppassword database table > /home/name/www/db.xml I obtain one XML file like this:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58710351/db.xml

How can I obtain the same schema (structure) than phpmyadmin xml export option using mysqldump?

Thank you very much

Comment: mysqldump and phpmyadmin are two different tools, with different usecases. You could try and transform one format into another, but I don't think it's worth the effort. Personally I would stick to the standard SQL format for mysqldump and use this for PITR.

Comment: Thank you. I'd made a php script instead. Cheers.